# Munkres Topology, page 102, questions 19:c and 19:d

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

**PROBLEM**

> If $A \subset X$, we define the **boundary** of $A$ by the equation
>   $$\text{Bd } A = \bar{A} \cap \overline{X - A}.$$
>
> > *[Munkres Topology, page 102, question 19:c]* Show that
> >     $$U \text{ is open } \iff \text{Bd } U = \bar{U} - U.$$
> >
> > *[Munkres Topology, page 102, question 19:d]* If $U$ is open, is it true that $U = \text{Int }(\bar{U})$?  Justify your answer.

**MY ATTEMPT**

I am pretty sure I must somehow use the results in either [Munkres Topology, page 102, question 19:a](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2417670) or [Munkres Topology, page 102, question 19:b](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2417688), but I am having trouble seeing how.

Sure, I can think of examples where both
$$U \text{ is open } \iff \text{Bd } U = \bar{U} - U$$
and
$$U \text{ is open } \implies U = \text{Int }(\bar{U})$$
hold.
(It suffices to take either $U=\mathbb{R}$ or $U=\emptyset$ under the usual topology.)

Risking looking dumb in this forum, let me try to prove [19:c]:

Suppose that $U$ is open. By a result in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2417709/472657), $\overline U = \text{Int } U$.  But $\overline{U} = \text{Int } U \cup \text{Bd } U$ (by [Munkres Topology, page 102, question 19:a](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2417670)).  *Now, I am stuck here, and I honestly do not know how to go further*.

Lastly, I think the solution for [19:d] must somehow use some result(s) from [19:c], but again I am not sure how.

**QUESTIONS**

> > **(1)** How do you show [19:c]?
> >
> > **(2)** What is a counterexample (if any) for [19:d]?  Otherwise, how do we go about proving it?

Answer (score 4):

For (1), suppose $U$ is open. If $x$ belongs to $\operatorname{Bd}(U)$, you want to show that $x$ is a point of the closure of $U$, but not a point of $U$ itself. Since every neighborhood of $x$ contains points from $U$ and $U^c$, $x$ cannot be an interior point of $U$, so $x$ is a point of the closure of $U$, but not a point of $U$ itself.

For the other inclusion, if $x\in\overline U-U$, then every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $U$ since $x\in\overline U$. Since $x$ is not a point of $U$, it is not an interior point of $U$. I'll let you finish that one.

Now, if $\operatorname{Bd}(U) = \overline U - U = \overline U\cap U^c$, we claim $U$ is open. We will do this by showing that $U^c$ is closed. Suppose that $x$ is a limit point of $U^c$. If $x\in U$, then every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point from $U^c$ and a point from $U$, so that $x$ is a boundary point of $U$. But then $x$ belongs to $U^c\cap U$, which is impossible, so the claim is proved.

For (2), think about the sets $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ as subsets of $\Bbb R$ with the standard topology.

Comment: For (2), I did not quite get what you meant when you suggested that I consider the sets $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 2)$.  Did you mean that I should consider their union instead, @AOrtiz?

Comment: @ArchimedesPlutonium I am leaving my hint for (2) as it is. Think about it.

Comment: I think I get it now.  I should consider the intersection of $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ instead, which is empty (and therefore, open).

Indeed I have
$$U = (0,1) \cap (1,2) = \emptyset \neq \operatorname{Int}(\overline{U}) = \operatorname{Int}(\overline{(0,1) \cap (1,2)}) = \operatorname{Int}(\overline{(0,1)} \cap \overline{(1,2)}) = \operatorname{Int}([0,1] \cap [1,2]) = \operatorname{Int}(\{1\}) = \emptyset.$$

OHH NO.

Comment: @ArchimedesPlutonium Their intersection is empty, so the closure of their intersection is also empty, so the interior of the closure of their intersection is empty, so you're not there yet. It's not true in this case that the closure of their intersection is the same as the intersection of their closures.